# Prove a set $I=[0,\infty)$ is not an open interval.

Tags: calculus

$(\exists y \in I)$ $(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})$ $x<y\Rightarrow x\notin I$.

I am trying to prove that the set $I=[0,\infty)$ is not an open interval.

So I know there exists a $y$ such that the statement is valid for all $x$. I think I need to set $y=0$ (a value in the set) then say that $x<0$. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: It seems what you want to prove that $(\exists y \in I)(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) (x<y\Rightarrow x\notin I)$. Your choice for $y$ is fine. What's keeping you from proving $(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) (x<0\Rightarrow x\notin I)$?

Comment: Just to stir the pot: what is the definition of an open interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that $$(\exists y \in I)(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})x<y\Rightarrow x\notin I$$ is your definition of not open? If so, it looks to me like you are already done. If you set $y=0$ and let $x<y$ then clearly $x \notin [0,\infty)$ so $I$ is not open. You don't need to consider the case of $x \geq 0$ as that isn't relevant to your definition of not open.

Comment: The first part of the proof was actually to negate $(\forall y \in I) (\exists x \in \mathbb{R})$ such that $x<y$ and $x \in I$ so it gave me the above. Then I was meant to prove the set is not an open interval. So by negation - it is actually proving it?

Comment: Your negation is correct, and in doing that you gave yourself a definition of "not open". Since you satisfied the definition of "not open" for $I$, you have proved it :)